# Different number of results with sesame2 and jena

Tags: sparql, jena, sesame

I'm writing some queries which are being run on both jena and sesame2. Most of them are working correctly under sesame2 except when i specify the depth of a path. For example, if I run this query under sesame it gives me 8 results whereas jena gives 217 (the correct number).

```
PREFIX edge: <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#> 
PREFIX property: <http://danielfrentz.com/property#> 
select  distinct ?start ?reached where{ 
?start property:id \"v1\". 
?start (edge:uses | edge:implements | edge:extends)+ ?reached.
filter(?start != ?reached)}
```

So my question is, does sesame2 have a different definition of the path depth syntax? or is there another reason why I might be getting different results?

Thanks.

Additional details:

I'm using 2.6.10 and trying out 2.7 beta.

The smallest example graph I have is the following (sorry its so long):

```
@prefix edge: <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#>.
@prefix edge: <http://danielfrentz.com/property#>.
<http://danielfrentz.com/v2> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#name> "Class3".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v2> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#abstract> "false".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v2> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#type> "class".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v2> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#namespace>    "com.example".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v2> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#id> "v2".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v1> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#name> "Class2".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v1> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#abstract> "false".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v1> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#type> "class".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v1> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#namespace>      "com.example".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v1> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#id> "v1".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v3> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#name> "Class4".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v3> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#abstract> "false".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v3> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#type> "class".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v3> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#namespace> "com.example".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v3> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#id> "v3".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v4> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#name> "AbstractClass1".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v4> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#abstract> "true".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v4> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#type> "class".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v4> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#namespace>   "com.example".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v4> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#id> "v4".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v0> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#name> "Class1".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v0> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#abstract> "false".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v0> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#type> "class".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v0> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#namespace>  "com.example".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v0> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#id> "v0".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v5> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#name> "Interface1".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v5> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#abstract> "true".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v5> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#type> "interface".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v5> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#namespace>    "com.example".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v5> <http://danielfrentz.com/property#id> "v5".
<http://danielfrentz.com/v3> <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#extends>     <http://danielfrentz.com/v4>.
<http://danielfrentz.com/v2> <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#uses>    <http://danielfrentz.com/v3>.
<http://danielfrentz.com/v4> <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#uses> <http://danielfrentz.com/v2>.
<http://danielfrentz.com/v5> <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#uses> <http://danielfrentz.com/v0>.
<http://danielfrentz.com/v1> <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#implements> <http://danielfrentz.com/v5>.
<http://danielfrentz.com/v0> <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#uses> <http://danielfrentz.com/v1>.
```

The query is:

```
PREFIX edge: <http://danielfrentz.com/edge#>
PREFIX property: <http://danielfrentz.com/property#>
select  distinct ?start ?reached where{
?start property:id \"v1\". 
?start (edge:uses | edge:implements | edge:extends){1,3} ?reached.
FILTER (?start != ?reached)}
```

and the results are:

```
start start=http://danielfrentz.com/v1
reached reached=http://danielfrentz.com/v5
```

there should be 2 results not 1.

I should also add that when I dont use a property path (ie i use + instead of {1,3}) it gives the correct number of results.

Comment: The Sesame people would probably appreciate a complete, minimal example. Complete=>some data and the expected result ; minimal=>no larger than necessary (not 217 results, as simple a query as possible).

Comment: In addition, please let us know which version of Sesame you are using. Property paths are a new feature. Both the official definition in the SPARQL spec and the implementation in Sesame have changed several times over various releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction that you are using with an lower and upper bound on the path length (`{1,3}`) is no longer an officially supported SPARQL feature, it was removed from the SPARQL specification in one of the more recent updates.

Sesame's SPARQL query parser still accepts the construction. I tested your query on Sesame 2.7.0-beta1 and you are correct, it does not produce the expected answer (whereas using `+`, which *is* still an official SPARQL feature, does work correctly). So this is a bug in Sesame's query parser. However, given that the `{1, 3}` construction is no longer officially part of SPARQL, I'm not sure it will be fixed - it's more likely that in a next Sesame release the construction will result in a syntax error instead.

Comment: As of the latest release of SPARQL 1.1, the only way to accomplish `prop{1,3}`, AFAIK, is an expression like `prop|(prop/prop)|(prop/prop/prop)`. This, admittedly, doesn't really scale well to longer paths.

Comment: @sdesciencelover

I tried using prop|(prop/prop)|(prop/prop/prop) and sadly i get 1 result again...although it works with jena.

The results im expecting are:

    start http://danielfrentz.com/node#v1
    reached http://danielfrentz.com/node#v5

    start http://danielfrentz.com/node#v1
    reached http://danielfrentz.com/node#v0

Comment: Heres an interesting note (perhaps I should create a new question?)

If I use prop then i get 1 -> 5 as expected but if i use prop/prop/prop I also get 1 -> 5 (don't expect any then, should be 1 -> 0 for prop/prop)